# Can I safely ignore these errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    channel = client.get_channel (649024513614282764)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Edited Message", description=f"Message sent by {before.author.mention} ({before.author}) in {before.channel.mention}", color=0xffff00, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
    embed.add_field(name=f"{before.content}", value=f"{after.content}", inline=False)
    if channel is None:
        print("Channel not found")
    else:
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

When I run the above, it's running as intended. However it's chucking

```
Exception has occurred: HTTPException
400 BAD REQUEST (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.0.name: This field is required
In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required
```

I'm ignoring the errors for now, since it's working. Will this cause an issue further down the line? If so, how can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Does the message being edited have content?  Are you seeing the embed get posted?

Comment: The embedded message shows the content no problem. It just shows the errors in console  @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your embed isn't being sent because `before.content` and `after.content` are empty strings.
Hence the error telling you that those fields are required.
The message in question is likely from a bot and only has an embed.
You can handle this by simply checking for the existence of `before.content` and `after.content` before you add the field to the embed.

Comment: It is posting the ```before.content``` and the ```after.content``` no problem at all. The only problem is the errors that are appearing, I'm ignoring them for now, but in the long run will it cause issues ?

Comment: Again, the error is occurring because you're attempting to send an embed with an empty field and value. This happens when `before.content` and `after.content` are empty strings in the cases when a message with only an embed is edited.