# Log embed thinks it's empty (on_message_edit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

To start with, I'm trying to make my bot log message editing. Basically that code **works** and **logs** messages that were edited, but it causes some problems in the terminal:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 BAD REQUEST (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required
```

Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    editembed = discord.Embed(
        timestamp=after.created_at,
        description = f"<@!{before.author.id}>**'s message was edited in** <#{before.channel.id}>.",
        colour = discord.Colour(0x00FF00)
        ) 
    editembed.set_author(name=f'{before.author.name}#{before.author.discriminator}', icon_url=before.author.avatar_url)
    editembed.set_footer(text=f"Author ID:{before.author.id} • Message ID: {before.id}")
    editembed.add_field(name='Before:', value=before.content, inline=False)
    editembed.add_field(name="After:", value=after.content, inline=False)
    channel = client.get_channel(665307525897519105)
    await channel.send(embed=editembed)
```

I can't understand why it decides that the `value` is empty. Can someone help to fix these errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I safely ignore these errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673603/can-i-safely-ignore-these-errors)

Comment: I mean the answer for question you suggested based on that the message with this embed can't be send. In my case everything works, it doesn't affect anything, just causes errors in terminal.

Comment: When the edited message has content besides just an embed, your event handler will successfully send your embed. Otherwise, if the message has an empty string as `before.content` or `after.content`, the embed will fail to send, as Discord responds with a 400 error. This is exactly the same as what's happening in the other linked question.

Comment: Do you have an example of non-empty before/after content that this is happening for?

Comment: Harmon, because I'm new to Python maybe I don't understand some simple things, but as you said "the embed will fail to send" I want to accent on that the embed doesn't fail to send, everything works just fine and only error appears in terminal it doesn't cause any failure in sending the embed (and etc.) it just appears and does nothing. [I hope I won't mess up markdown](https://prnt.sc/qmob26)

Comment: Again, you're seeing the embeds that are sent for message edits that have content. In those cases `before.content` and `after.content` are not empty strings. As I said, if the message edit event is for a message with only an embed, your event handler will error with the highlighted exception.

Comment: @TheBrokennWorld Try adding some print statements that print `repr(before.content)` and `repr(after.content)`.  That will let you see exactly which payloads it's failing for

Comment: Thanks alot, but I can't understand how to check for the existence of ```before.content``` and ```after.content```? Can you advise how better to do it?

Comment: [Empty strings are falsey](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), so you can just `not` them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I searched around on google for some time and found a solution which was by adding  `+ "\u200b"` after both `value=before.content` and `value=after.content`. I also used embed instead of editembed. So try this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        timestamp=after.created_at,
        description = f"<@!{before.author.id}>**'s message was edited in** <#{before.channel.id}>.",
        colour = discord.Colour(0x00FF00)
        ) 
    embed.set_author(name=f'{before.author.name}#{before.author.discriminator}', icon_url=before.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Author ID:{before.author.id} • Message ID: {before.id}")
    embed.add_field(name='Before:', value=before.content + "\u200b", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="After:", value=after.content + "\u200b", inline=False)
    channel = bot.get_channel(665307525897519105)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Link to the github page that helped me: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/643

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong variables try this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        timestamp=after.created_at,
        description = f"<@!{before.author.id}>**'s message was edited in** <#{before.channel.id}>.",
        colour = discord.Colour(0x00FF00)
        ) 
    embed.set_author(name=f'{before.author.name}#{before.author.discriminator}', icon_url=before.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Author ID:{before.author.id} • Message ID: {before.id}")
    embed.add_field(name='Before:', value=before.content, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="After:", value=after.content, inline=False)
    channel = bot.get_channel(665307525897519105)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```